# Zend Framework: Need Auto Loading on IIS7 help

Tags: zend-framework, autoloader

ZF is wearing me thin. I cannot get one instance of the AutoLoader to work without first using this to add it as a resource

```
require_once ('Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php');
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
           'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/helpers',
           'namespace' => 'Application_',
       ));

$resourceLoader->addResourceType('form', 'forms/', 'Form')
           ->addResourceType('functions', 'functions/', 'Functions')
           ->addResourceType('menus', 'menus/', 'Menu')
           ->addResourceType('acls', 'acls/', 'Acls');
```

Now I am trying to load a plugin but ZF complains about the paths when I know the files exist.

```
// located in application/controllers/plugins
    require('controllers\plugins\Acl.php');
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Controller_Plugin_Acl($acl));
```

Why do I have to use require Is this a IIS7 thing? I thought the AutoLoader was supposed to take care of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is an IIS problem. I think this is a improper use of `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource`.

You're telling the autoloader via `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` to add the namespace `Application` and that it is located in the basePath `APPLICATION_PATH . '/helpers'`.

From this if I try:

```
new Application_Menu_Primary();
```

ZF should find it in `APPLICATION_PATH . '/helpers/menus/Primary.php'`. Is that really where you want to find the file? I am guessing not. Further, trying this: `Application_Controller_Plugin_Acl` will never be included cause your missing the resource type `Controller_Plugin` and it's directory inside `APPLICATION_PATH . '/helpers'` (I doubt you want that).

I would suggest that you remove this usage of `Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` all together and add your namespace into your application's `/library` directory and create the following directory structure:

```
/library/Application/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php
/library/Application/Form/
...etc
```

Then, you need to add `/library` path to your PHP include_path via index.php. (I thought this was standard)

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Finally, add the `Application` namespace to your `application.ini`:

```
autoloaderNamespaces.app = 'Application'
```

That should clear up your problems. I suggest you learn more about the purpose of this class [`Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html).

Comment: Wow! Brady thanks! I used Zend Tool to create the project so there is a lot that I don't know about the setting up of the structure. This really helps. Going to give it try as soon I get of the train.